# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get ClosableLazy value after it has been closed

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, playframework-2.0, akka

I am working on a Rest API implemented using Play Framework 2.3. I have some endpoints that make use of Akka actors to produce the result, and I could unit test them unfortunately because of this error. The other end points test fine. To run a test, I make use of a fakeApplication object, something like:

```
       @BeforeClass
        public static void initResources(){
            Helpers.start(getFakeApplicationInstance());
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void cleanupResources(){

          Helpers.stop(getFakeApplicationInstance());
        }

       public static FakeApplication getFakeApplicationInstance() {
            if(fakeApp == null)
                fakeApp = Helpers.fakeApplication(TestUtil.testSettings(), new GlobalCommon());

            return fakeApp;
        }
 @Test
    public void test() {
        running(testServer(3333, getFakeApplicationInstance()), () -> {
         // test go here

}));
}
```

I am not sure how does the fakeApplication works with the akkaSystem, but it seems like there is something missing. Here is the stack trace:

```
Test rest.RestItemTest.marshalRoomDetails failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get ClosableLazy value after it has been closed, took 7.732 sec
[error]     at play.core.ClosableLazy.get(ClosableLazy.scala:49)
[error]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPlugin.applicationSystem(Akka.scala:71)
[error]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$$anonfun$system$1.apply(Akka.scala:29)
[error]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$$anonfun$system$1.apply(Akka.scala:29)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$.system(Akka.scala:29)
[error]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(Akka.scala)
[error]     at play.libs.Akka.system(Akka.java:25)
[error]     at utils.GlobalCommonTest.onStart(GlobalCommonTest.java:186)
[error]     at utils.APIGlobalTest.onStart(APIGlobalTest.java:16)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:22)
[error]     at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:220)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error]     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
[error]     at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
[error]     at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:470)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:486)
```

I only get that when I call endpoints that make use of Actors. Any help or experience sharing, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was mainly due to the reuse of the same application instance in more than one test. When an application context is used in one test, it launches the plugins and starts the context. At the end of the test, the application is shutdown, which shutdown the plugins as well. If you try restart this same application instance, then plugins are not restarted because they are ClosableLazy objects which can only be closed once. The solution was to not use the singelton pattern and create a new application instance for each single test. So intead of:

```
 public static FakeApplication getFakeApplicationInstance() {
            if(fakeApp == null)
                fakeApp = Helpers.fakeApplication(TestUtil.testSettings(), new GlobalCommon());

            return fakeApp;
        }
```

The solution was:

```
 public static FakeApplication getFakeApplicationInstance() {
            return Helpers.fakeApplication(TestUtil.testSettings(), new GlobalCommon());
        }
```

I hope this will help someone.